# Azure Search Azure SQL Database Integration

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

I am currently trying to integrate Azure Search to my Azure SQL Database in order to enable Spatial searcing. In my index there is a field that is type of Edm.GeographyPoint. What is Sql database's column type should be?, because Geography type did not work.

Additionally, my datasource's datachange field is like this:

`"dataChangeDetectionPolicy" : {
       "@odata.type" : "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.HighWaterMarkChangeDetectionPolicy",
       "highWaterMarkColumnName" : "RowLastVersion"
    },
    "dataDeletionDetectionPolicy" : { 
       "@odata.type" : "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.SoftDeleteColumnDeletionDetectionPolicy",
       "softDeleteColumnName" : "Deleted", 
       "softDeleteMarkerValue" : "0" 
    }`

Is there anything additionally i have to do for auto indexing?, Because These are also not working.

Azure Search is a perfect api. However, there is a lack of documents that we can use.

Comment: Hi Arda, 
I work on Azure Search. Geospatial types are not currently supported for auto-indexing. Please vote for this UserVoice suggestion to help us prioritize adding this feature: http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/7247670-support-for-geography-sql-server-column

Comment: Regarding your question about change detection policies, what errors are you seeing? Does your table have columns called "RowLastVersion" and "Deleted"? What is the data type of those columns?

Thanks,
Eugene

Comment: Thank you for your comments. My table has columns RowLastVersion, which is Rowversion type, Deleted, which is varchar(1) type. I am not getting any error. Just, my changes in table does not affect Azure Search index.

Comment: Hi Arda, do you have a schedule set up for the indexer? And what is the interval on that schedule?

Comment: Yes, my indexer includes scheduler and it is set up 5 minutes

Comment: OK i'd like to take a deeper look. Could you email me your service name and indexer name at eugenesh at usual Microsoft domain? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out indexer schedule's startTime was set in the future. Invoking indexer using /run indexed as expected.